# When is the cut-locus normal coordinate collared

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a complete $d$-dimensional Riemannian manifold, $p \in M$ be fixed and let $C_p$ be the [cut-locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_locus_(Riemannian_manifold)) of $p$.
Other than when $M$ is non-positively curved (in which $C_p=
\emptyset$ by [Cartan-Hadamard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem)) when is the cut-locus contained in a [collared neighbourhood](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703009/collar-neighbourhoods-for-topological-manifolds) ie: an open subset $U\subseteq M$ containing $C_p$ satisfying and a homeomorphism $f:U\rightarrow C_p \times [0,1)$ such that
$$
f[C_p]=C_p \times \{0\}.
$$

Comment: Collared by normal coordinates, or just topologically collared?

Comment: Just topologically

Comment: Could you define "topologically collared"? The cut locus $C_p$ is not a submanifold. For example on a surface it should be a topologically embedded tree, and so it cannot have a neighborhood homeomorphic to $[0,1]\times C_p$ because the latter is not a manifold.

Comment: And the tree need not be locally finite, as was famously shown by  Gluck and Singer in "Scattering of Geodesic Fields, I". Actually, in general on a surface, it is a graph not a tree, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.1759.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek I added in the definition of collared that I'm looking for.

Comment: As I explained in my comment above your definition of collared cannot work. Imagine that the cut locus $C$ in a surface is a tripod (the graph with 3 edges joined in a common vertex). Such examples are in the paper "Every graph is a cut locus" linked above. No neighborhood of a tripod in a $2$-manifold is homeomorphic to $C\times [0,1)$ because the latter is not a manifold.

Comment: I’ve probably misread the question, but isn’t the answer no for the standard sphere?

Comment: @DeaneYang: right, the OP definition of "collared" fails for the round sphere.

Comment: This is impossible because $[0,1)$ is not a homology manifold. So $X\times [0,1)$ can never be a topological manifold for any $X$.

Comment: @VitaliKapovitch Why doesn't that contradict Theorem 2 of "Locally flat imbeddings of topological manifolds", Morton Brown, 1962 which states that the boundary of any metrizable manifold with boundary $M$ is collared?  Doesn't this use the fact that $\partial M \times [0,1)$ is homeomorphic to an open neiberhood of $\partial M$?

Comment: I'm assuming that $M$ has no boundary. Could you give an explicit example of what you mean by a collared neighborhood? For example, if $S \subset M$ is a smooth hypersurface, then any subset of $M$ that is homeomorphic to $S\times [0,1)$ is never open. On the other hand, any subset homeomorphic to $S\times (0,1)$ is.

Comment: @AIM_BLB that's certainly a correct theorem but you didn't say anything about boundary in your question  so I assumed you meant a manifold without boundary. For manifolds without boundary what you ask for is impossible unless the cut locus is empty. It is of course possible for manifolds with boundary (e.g. a closed disk in $R^n$)  provided you define cut locus appropriately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Permit me to include this nice image from Day & Li
to illustrate @Igor's point that "in general on a surface, it [the cut locus] is a graph not a tree."

---

[image]


<sup>The source point $p$ is on the cat's forehead,
the other side in this rear-view.</sup>

---

> Dey, Tamal K., and Kuiyu Li. "Cut locus and topology from surface point data." *In Proceedings of the 25th Symposium on Computational Geometry*, pp. 125-134. 2009.
>   [ACM link](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1542362.1542390).

In the paper they compute an approximation to the cut locus
on this model that pretty much follows the smooth curves
drawn above.